# Android Screen density qualifiers

Tags: android, android-screen

I understand how android picks density bucket.[This answer](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range) explains how android picks density buckets.

My question is why does android uses buckets instead of using the linear relation?

For example if device density is 232 then it belongs to its closest density bucket, hdpi bucket(240dpi) and the scaling factor is 1.5px/dp which we get from 240/160 = 1.5 and if we would have used linear relation then scaling factor would be 232/160.

Won't we have better precision with linear relation as compared to buckets?

Comment: "My question is why does android uses buckets instead of using the linear relation?" -- that would seem to require an infinite number of drawable resources.

Comment: Would it work if bucket logic was used just for selecting drawable resources and linear scaling was used for dp and sp?

Comment: My guess is that they wanted consistency between those approaches. Nothing is stopping you from using `DisplayMetrics` and doing your own linear scaling logic, for cases where that level of precision is needed (e.g., rendering an on-screen physical-distance ruler).

Comment: Thanks. And one more thing is there reason behind "160"

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand the question.

Comment: Oh, I ment the base 160 dpi wich is used to define mdpi and rest of the densities are defined with respect to this density.And for mdpi relation b/w dp and px is 1.

Comment: That's how CSS pixels work in Web development. I do not know whether Android's `dp` or CSS pixels came first.